# Wordpress paginated comments and comment_reply_link issue

Tags: wordpress, pagination, comments

So I have comments via wp_list_comments with pagination. The comments display correctly and pagination works. The issue I'm having is that when you click the comment reply link it navigates back to page 1 of the paginated pages. So on any paginated page I'm unable to reply to a comment on that page.

Obviously the comment_reply_link doesn't care that I'm on page 2, page 3, etc. It just wants to go the original post page to comment.

I'm thinking I should hook into comment_reply_link and tell it to use the current_page url as a base but not sure where to start. Not seeing a hook in the codex.

edit:

Should have added that I'm working with nested comments...many levels deep.

Using standard reply with $args

```
<?php echo comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 
'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add this code into your `wp_enqueue_scripts`hooks

```
if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
```